# How can I insert 59,670 rows inside the table using the console in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert 59,670 rows inside the table using the console in MySql but I got this result after starting to insert them.

```
INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('...', '...');
INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('...', '...');
INSERT INTO `MyTable` (`col1`, `col2`) VALUES ('...', '...');
etc... to 59,670 lines
```

[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOws7.png)

How can I solve it?

Comment: Your external link doesn't say anything.  But even if it did, you should really include a full description of your problem in the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When I add 3000 lines approximately, It will be added successfully but when add 59670 I get the result above so the problem is the console cannot add 59670 rows?

Comment: Most likely it is just too much input for the console.  Consider using `LOAD DATA`, which is MySQL's bulk loading tool.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Leave example please

Comment: @SE19 you can check Load Data in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68566945/i-have-a-lot-of-data-in-excel-and-i-want-to-add-them-to-mysql-database-how-can/68567399#68567399

Comment: *When I add 3000 lines approximately, It will be added successfully but when add 59670 I get the result above so the problem is the console cannot add 59670 rows?* Possible problem reasons: (1) Some timeout exceeded (2) @@max_allowed_packet exceeded.